# Port Forwarding based on URL hostname in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, port-forwarding

Example: I have two URLs

```
https:// www.abc.net  => maps to https://192.168.0.100:5000
https:// www.def.net  => maps to https://192.168.0.100:5001
```

Both servers running on the same Windows 10 PCs.

May I know how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Port forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) is forwarding traffic to a host based on specific ports. No additional information is used for this routing (i.e. any "destination" URLs). For routing specific URLs to particular local services, you'll likely want a [reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy).

In short, a reverse proxy takes requests from the Internet and forwards them to servers in an internal network. Importantly, it can often do this based on a particular URL received.

**Software**

For setting up a reverse proxy, two common solutions that would likely suit your needs are [Apache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server) and [Nginx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx). Both are open source web servers and both can be configured to act as reverse proxies (via Apache [virtual hosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/) or Nginx [server blocks](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server), respectively).

Windows builds of Apache with SSL are available from [Apache Lounge](https://www.apachelounge.com/download/) and Windows builds of Nginx (which also support SSL) are directly available from [Nginx](https://nginx.org/en/download.html).

**Caveats**

One thing to consider about a reverse proxy is that communications between a client and a local service may be limited by what the reverse proxy itself can pass.

In some cases, it could be preferable (or may even be necessary) to make a direct link between the client and a local service. For instance, assuming a router was mapping ports `5000` and `5001` to an internal host (e.g. `192.168.0.100`) and that `example.com` and `example.net` were pointed to that router, those ports/services would likely be externally available as e.g. `example.com:5000` and `example.net:5001`.

The basic downside to this is approach is that DNS doesn't use port information, so `example.net:5000` and `example.com:5001` would also map to the same services. However, for some types of communication, this might be the only option.

---

**Reverse Proxy Example (Overview)**

Assuming you decide to use Apache or Nginx as reverse proxy, while the individual configuration steps may be different, the basics are roughly the same:

1. Install your preferred solution (e.g. either Apache or Nginx).
2. Perform some basic configuration (so that it can respond to HTTP requests).
3. Enable/configure any appropriate proxy features (as needed).
4. Configure SSL support (since it appears you wish to respond to HTTPS URLs, based on your original question).
5. Use [virtual hosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/) (Apache) or [server blocks](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server) (Nginx) to create hosts for the domains you wish to proxy data for, then configure those hosts to pass data between a client and the desired local service.

---

*While the example below only covers using Apache as a reverse proxy, for Nginx, the steps outlined above are generally available on the web.*

---

**Reverse Proxy Example (Apache)**

*Assumptions*

Below is a bare-bones example of how to setup Apache from scratch as reverse proxy on Windows. Note that it isn't intended to address any of the finer points of general Apache, SSL or reverse proxy configuration beyond sending requests from basic URL A to local service B.

It also assumes that:

- The reverse proxy (i.e. Apache) is being installed on the same local server as the current services (ex. `192.168.0.100`), outside of any virtual machine.
- There are no services running on port `80` (HTTP) or `443` (HTTPS) on that host.
- DNS is already set up correctly for any domains (e.g. `example.com` and `example.net` already point to the appropriate router/local network).
- SSL certificates and keys are available for the domains you wish to proxy.
- The local services you wish to proxy to are not using HTTPS (SSL) themselves.
- Port forwarding is already set up correctly (i.e. ports `5000` and `5001` are mapped to `192.168.0.100`). Note that for this example, ports `80` and `443` will also need to be mapped to the host with the reverse proxy (again, ex. `192.168.0.100`).

*Installation*

1. [Download Apache from Apache Lounge](https://www.apachelounge.com/download/) and extract it. For this example, place the folder labeled `Apache24` into `C:\` on your local server (i.e `C:\Apache24` on `192.168.0.100`).

   Apache being built as 32-bit (ex. `httpd-2.4.43-win32-VS16.zip`) or 64-bit (ex. `httpd-2.4.43-win64-VS16.zip`) doesn't matter in this instance, so you can choose either one.
2. Download the matching Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015-2019 from the same page (either `vc_redist_x86` for `httpd-2.4.43-win32-VS16.zip` or `vc_redist_x64` for `httpd-2.4.43-win64-VS16.zip`). Double-click the executable to install it.

   If the installer displays the option to "Repair" an existing redistributable installation, you can safely cancel the installation entirely, as you already have an appropriate version of that redistributable installed.
3. It is possible to install Apache as a service in Windows by running `httpd -k install -n "Apache2.4"` from the command line (`httpd.exe` is located under ex. `C:\Apache24\bin`). If you decide to do this, use an administrative command prompt and *do not* use a name for the service other than `Apache2.4`.

*Configuration (Overview)*

- When editing any configuration file for Apache, you should use a plain text editor such as Windows Notepad or a third-party editor like [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/).
- In the context of the steps given below, "uncomment" means to remove any leading `#` sign in front of one or more lines in a configuration file and "comment out" means to add a leading `#` sign in front of one or more lines in a configuration file:

  ```
  # This line is commented out
  This line is uncommented
  ```
- In the individual configuration examples below, `[...]` is just an place holder intended to indicate "more irrelevant stuff here" (i.e. it doesn't actually go in the configuration file).
- The majority of the configuration steps listed below are done in `httpd.conf` (ex. `C:\Apache24\conf\httpd.conf`), as it is the main configuration file for Apache.
- For general SSL support and implementing the virtual hosts needed for a reverse proxy setup, there are changes that need to be made in `httpd-ssl.conf` (ex. `C:\Apache24\conf\extra\httpd-ssl.conf`) and `httpd-vhosts.conf` (ex. `C:\Apache24\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf`) as well.
- Configuration files need to be saved and Apache restarted (assuming it is running) for any configuration changes to take effect.

*HTTP Configuration*

Apache is already set up for handling basic HTTP requests out of the box, especially when placed in `C:\Apache24` (the default directory the Apache Lounge version of Apache assumes it resides in). However, a warning will be emitted if the default `ServerName` directive in `httpd.conf` isn't uncommented. So make the following change:

*ex. httpd.conf*

```
[...]
# ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.
# This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify
# it explicitly to prevent problems during startup.
#
# If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
#
ServerName www.example.com:80
```

For this example, the value of this `ServerName` directive doesn't matter, as long as it *isn't* one of the domains you wish to proxy (i.e. leaving it `www.example.com:80` is fine).

*Enabling Proxy Modules*

Apache comes with a number of optional modules which enable additional features in Apache, such as the ability to proxy incoming requests to local services. These "extra" modules are listed in `httpd.conf` but are typically disabled (commented out) by default.

You don't mention the services you are attempting to proxy, but you should probably enable at least `mod_proxy`, `mod_proxy_html`, `mod_proxy_http` and `mod_xml2enc` in `httpd.conf` by uncommenting them like so:

*ex. httpd.conf*

```
[...]
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so 
[...]
LoadModule proxy_html_module modules/mod_proxy_html.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
[...]
LoadModule xml2enc_module modules/mod_xml2enc.so
```

`mod_proxy` is a "base" module that other proxy modules rely on, so it should always be uncommented. `mod_proxy_html` and `mod_proxy_http` should allow most web pages to be proxied successfully and `mod_xml2enc` helps ensure non-ASCII characters in proxied pages are displayed correctly.

*SSL Certificates (Overview)*

- Please note that the instruction below assume that you have an existing self-signed SSL certificate and matching key specifically for `www.example.com` (as in the actual domain `www.example.com`, not merely as a documentation placeholder). These aren't directly used for proxying, but are required when including the default Apache `httpd-ssl.conf` file (unless additional configuration is done to that file, which is mostly skipped here).
- If you do not have these files, I would suggest using [this website](https://www.selfsignedcertificate.com/) to generate them. It only takes a moment and the domain in the link currently defaults to `www.example.com`. All you should need to do is click the button marked `Generate` and then use the resulting links to download the appropriate `.cert` and `.key` files (e.g. `12345678-www.example.com.cert` and `12345678-www.example.com.key`).
- If you want to generate a self-signed certificate locally, SLProWeb offers [Windows builds of OpenSSL](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) that can be used from the command line, but those steps aren't covered here.
- If you need free SSL certificates for the domain names you wish to proxy (these certificates are used later in the "virtual hosts" section of this example), I might suggest looking at [ZeroSSL](https://zerossl.com/) to obtain certificates from [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/). They only last 3 months, but can be renewed indefinitely at no charge. Plus, ZeroSSL offers a simple, fairly easy-to-use command line client for obtaining/renewing Let's Encrypt certificates.
- Be aware that it is important *not* to use encrypted SSL key files on Windows with Apache. Apache does not support SSL passphrases on Win32. If any of your SSL key files are encrypted with a passphrase, you must use OpenSSL to remove that passphrase before using it with Apache on Windows.

*SSL (HTTPS) Configuration*

1. To enable SSL support in Apache, enable the `mod_ssl` module in `httpd.conf` by uncommenting it. For this example, you will also need to enable (uncomment) `mod_socache_shmcb`:

   *ex. httpd.conf*

   ```
   [...]
   LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
   #LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
   LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
   [...]
   ```
2. For expediency, we will also include the default Apache SSL configuration file (`httpd-ssl.conf`). To do this, uncomment the following line near the end of `httpd.conf`:

   *ex. httpd.conf*

   ```
   # Secure (SSL/TLS) connections
   Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
   ```
3. Create one (or more) folders to hold your `www.example.com` SSL certificate and key file. For this example, these folders should be under `C:\Apache24`. Place the appropriate files in the folder(s) you created.
4. Open `httpd-ssl.conf` (ex. `C:\Apache24\conf\extra\httpd-ssl.conf`). Look for the line `SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin` and disable it (comment it out):

   *ex. httpd-ssl.conf*

   ```
   [...]
   #   Pass Phrase Dialog:
   #   Configure the pass phrase gathering process.
   #   The filtering dialog program (`builtin' is an internal
   #   terminal dialog) has to provide the pass phrase on stdout.
   #SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
   ```
5. Further down in `httpd-ssl.conf`, look for the `SSLCertificateFile` and `SSLCertificateKeyFile` directives and change the paths after them to point to your `www.example.com` certificate and key files (wherever you placed them in Step 3, above):

   *ex. httpd-ssl.conf*

   ```
   [...]
   SSLCertificateFile "${SRVROOT}/path/to/12345678-www.example.com.cert"
   [...]
   SSLCertificateKeyFile "${SRVROOT}/path/to/12345678-www.example.com.key"
   [...]
   ```

*Testing (Preliminary)*

You should have a working, SSL enabled Apache server at this point (though not a reverse proxy just yet). To test this:

- Save any changes you made to `httpd.conf` and `httpd-ssl.conf` (if you haven't already).
- Navigate to your Apache `bin` directory (ex. `C:\Apache24\bin`).
- Open a command window in that directory (ex. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Right-Click a blank area in Explorer and choose the option to *Open Command Prompt Here*).
- Run `httpd.exe`:

  [image: Running httpd.exe - screenshot]
- This command window should remain open without any additional errors or warnings and without returning to the command line (e.g. `C:\Apache24\bin>`).
- Assuming this is the case, you should be able to enter e.g. `http://192.168.0.100` and `https://192.168.0.100` into your browser and get a white page that states `It works!`.
- Assuming your DNS is configured properly and you have port forwarded ports `80` and `443` to ex. `http://192.168.0.100`, using the HTTP and HTTPS versions of `abc.net` and `def.net` should yield the same page.
- For SSL connections (ex. `https://192.168.0.100`), your browser may warn you that the certificate name doesn't match and/or that the certificate is self-signed. In this instance, it is safe to ignore any warnings and proceed with the connection.

*Testing (Issues)*

- If any errors or warnings are displayed at the command line, fix them before proceeding.
- If `httpd.exe` immediately stops (goes back to the command line) without any additional output, check the Apache `error.log` (ex. `C:\Apache24\logs\error.log`) for any issues e.g. with your SSL configuration.
- If you cannot reach ex. `https://192.168.0.100`, ensure that any firewall on that host isn't blocking web traffic and that ports `80` and `443` are forwarded correctly to that host.
- In some rarer cases, using ex. `abc.net` and `def.net` may not be possible without additional considerations or steps. This could be due to a router not supporting [hairpinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning) (NAT Loopback) or worse, an ISP having [Carrier-Grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT) (CGNAT) or actively blocking ports.
- Hairpinning issues can be bypassed by accessing ex. `abc.net` and `def.net` from a device not connected to your local network (e.g. a smartphone connected to a carrier's network).
- CGNAT or similar may require a server completely outside your local network to act as an additional proxy to your network and isn't covered here.

*Virtual Host (Reverse Proxy) Configuration*

1. After testing Apache (above), close the command window for `httpd.exe` to stop Apache.
2. Reopen `httpd.conf` (ex. `C:\Apache24\conf\httpd.conf`) and enable the default Apache virtual hosts configuration file (`httpd-vhosts.conf`) by uncommenting the following line:

   *ex. httpd.conf*

   ```
   # Virtual hosts
   Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
   ```
3. Next, open `httpd-vhosts.conf` (ex. `C:\Apache24\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf`) and comment out the existing virtual host example entries:

   *ex. httpd-vhosts.conf*

   ```
   [...]
   #<VirtualHost *:80>
        #ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
        #DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/docs/dummy-host.example.com"
        #ServerName dummy-host.example.com
        #ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
        #ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
        #CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
   #</VirtualHost>

   #<VirtualHost *:80>
       #ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
       #DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/docs/dummy-host2.example.com"
       #ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
       #ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
       #CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
   #</VirtualHost>
   ```
4. Add the following example virtual hosts to the end of `httpd-vhosts.conf`:

   *ex. httpd-vhosts.conf*

   ```
   # Redirect HTTP to HTTPS for http://example.com
   <VirtualHost *:80>

       ServerName example.com
       ServerAlias www.example.com

       Redirect permanent / https://example.com/

   </VirtualHost>

   # Redirect HTTP to HTTPS for http://example.net
   <VirtualHost *:80>

       ServerName example.net
       ServerAlias www.example.net

       Redirect permanent / https://example.net/

   </VirtualHost>

   # Redirect HTTPS requests for https://example.com to ex. 192.168.0.100:5000
   <VirtualHost *:443>

       ServerName example.com
       ServerAlias www.example.com

       SSLEngine on
       SSLOptions +StrictRequire

       SSLCertificateFile "${SRVROOT}/path/to/www.example.com.crt"
       SSLCertificateKeyFile "${SRVROOT}/path/to/www.example.com.key"

       # Required by first virtual SSL host
       #SSLProtocol TLSv1

       #ProxyPass / http://192.168.0.100:5000/
       #ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.0.100:5000/

       # Localhost
       ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
       ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/

   </VirtualHost>

   # Redirect HTTPS requests for https://example.net to ex. 192.168.0.100:5001
   <VirtualHost *:443>

       ServerName example.net
       ServerAlias www.example.net

       SSLEngine on
       SSLOptions +StrictRequire

       SSLCertificateFile "${SRVROOT}/path/to/www.example.net.crt"
       SSLCertificateKeyFile "${SRVROOT}/path/to/www.example.net.key"

       # Required by first virtual SSL host
       #SSLProtocol TLSv1

       #ProxyPass / http://192.168.0.100:5001/
       #ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.0.100:5001/

       # Localhost
       ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5001/
       ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5001/

   #</VirtualHost>
   ```
5. Modify this updated example for your needs. In particular:

   - Unlike in `httpd.conf` and `httpd-ssl.conf`, substitute your actual domains (e.g. `abc.net` and `def.net`) for `example.com` and `example.net` (e.g. just do a simple search/replace).
   - Change the `SSLCertificateFile` and `SSLCertificateKeyFile` directives to point to the appropriate SSL certificate and key files for each of your domains (again, ex. `abc.net` and `def.net`). This example assumes you are dropping them in roughly the same folder(s) as your actual `www.example.com` certificate and key files from the prior "SSL" section (above).
   - While these examples omit per-host logging for space, you can add logging directives to any of the virtual hosts above if you wish.
6. Save `httpd-vhosts.conf` after making the necessary changes above.

While Apache is running, your services on `192.168.0.100:5000` and `192.168.0.100:5001` should now be returned by either the HTTP or HTTPS versions of `abc.net` and `def.net`, respectively (with or without the `www` prefix, assuming the non-www versions are set in DNS).

Comment: outstanding answer!